# Are Delphi interface uses transitive?

Tags: delphi

Say some program A uses some unit B which uses some unit C:

```
program A;
uses B;

unit B;
interface
uses C;
```

Does A implicitly use C as well?

(I am not asking about best practices, but from a compiler/static analysis point of view.)

Comment: If you mean `A` being able to access `C` just because it uses `B`, then no. Compiled, yes. But you need to explicitly `use` `C` within `A`. But you could just try for yourself, it's an extremely trivial test.

Comment: For what it's worth: there's some loose relationship between Pascal's `interface` and `implementation` sections and C's `.h`- and `.c`-files, but Pascal's `uses`-clause looks so much gentler than C's rather crude `#include` _pre_-processor-instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret the question.

1. Does program A include unit C?

Yes it does.

2. Can the program A source .dpr file see public names declared by unit C?

No.